# Notice: Undefined index. POST seems not to Transfer

Tags: php, html, post

i am currently trying to make a small web application. I got a checkbox form that should transfer via POST to another side where i stores a bool in a sql table. This is the form:

```
echo "<form action=eintragen.php method='POST'>";


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $array[] = $row['arbeitsstationen'];
}
            
$rowcnt1 = $rowcnt - $rowcnt;
while($rowcnt > 0 ){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>"."<input type='checkbox' name='Mo $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' value='Mo $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' >".$array[$rowcnt1]."</th>";
    echo "<th>"."<input type='checkbox' name='Di $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' value='Mo $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' >".$array[$rowcnt1]."</th>";
    echo "<th>"."<input type='checkbox' name='Mi $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' value='Mo $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' >".$array[$rowcnt1]."</th>";
    echo "<th>"."<input type='checkbox' name='Do $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' value='Mo $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' >".$array[$rowcnt1]."</th>";
    echo "<th>"."<input type='checkbox' name='Fr $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' value='Mo $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' >".$array[$rowcnt1]."</th>";
    echo "<th>"."<input type='checkbox' name='Sa $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' value='Mo $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' >".$array[$rowcnt1]."</th>";
    echo "<th>"."<input type='checkbox' name='So $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' value='Mo $array[$rowcnt1] $rowcnt1' >".$array[$rowcnt1]."</th>";
                
     $rowcnt = $rowcnt - 1;
     $rowcnt1 = $rowcnt1 + 1;
     echo "</tr>";
}
```

and this is part of page 2 what isn't working:

```
$set = "Mo $array1[$u] $u";

var_dump($_POST["$set"]);

if(isset($_POST["$set"])) {
    $setdaymo = "UPDATE ArbeitsKW$week SET $array1[$u] = 1 WHERE Datum = $arr[$u]";
}else{
    $setdaysmo ="UPDATE ArbeitsKW$week SET $array1[$u] = 0 WHERE Datum = $arr[$u]";
}
        
if($con->query($setdaymo) === TRUE) {   
    echo "Klapt auch<br>";
}else {
    echo"war nichts <br>" ;
}
$u++;
$t--;
}
```

i checked and the given POST variables are right, but it seems like the POST isn't transferred correctly ... i got a bit more code on each sites, if you need more information i will add more.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Show us a `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Those field names look terrible. There is no need to name them this awfully, you have the same value in the `value` attribute already, so what would be the point of this redudant info in the first place? Give them a “simple” name with square brackets at the end, something `name="mycheckbox[]"` - for all of them. Then `$_POST['mycheckbox']` will be an array with the values of all the checked checkboxes, that you can easily loop over.

Comment: Also, in your if-statement, you set `$setdaymo` if the post is set, but you set `$setdaysmo` in the `else`-block. So if the post isn't set, you will try and execute a query from an undefined variable. It would also help if you told us _where_ that error occurs. What line?

Comment: It's very hard to know where it goes wrong when you're using a lot of variables that, for us, are completely unknown. Where does `$array1`, `$u` and `$arr` come from? What do they contain? What are the results of all those strings you're building? Imho, this question is incomplete atm.

Comment: @Lucca is the second file named eintragen.php and is in the same directory as the first file? Wow, that's a strange code - `$rowcnt1 = $rowcnt - $rowcnt;` You don't have rowcount. And the checkboxes should have the same name and different values only.

Comment: Hello, thx for the Answers, i know my way of notice thinks isn't any where near good, but i am learning ... var_dump gives me a NULL output.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson these are just numbers that are counting to get different results